# Длинные расчёты в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Я где-то в своём самоучителе видел, такую функцию, чтоб интерфейс не зависал во время длинных расчётов. Там было написано, что её надо вставлять где-то в середине расчётов. Самоучитель не маленький(670 стр.) и я не могу эту функцию найти!!! Не знаете, что это за функция?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой костыль это

```
Application.ProcessMessages;
```

Эта функция пропускает всю очередь поступивших в приложение сообщений системы.

В более сложном, но более производительном, варианте расчетные операции выносят в отдельный поток (нативный класс TThread), а промежуточные результаты в основной поток отправляются через асинхронные методы.

Comment: Вот именно это я, и видел!!! Спасибо!